# Javascript will not connect to html elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a connection between an input and a paragraph, where the paragraph was going to show the price * the amount of people. So if it originally costed 7 000 for one, then if the input would say 2, it would cost 14 000. It works on this page, however not on mine for some reason. Sorry i'm so horrible at this guys :/

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;

  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();

  div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
  a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      a[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      a[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

function playPause(btn, vid) {
  var vid = document.getElementById(vid);

  if (vid.paused) {
    vid.play();
    btn.innerHTML = '<img class="video-btns" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/pause_icon.png" />';
  } else {
    vid.pause();
    btn.innerHTML = '<img class="video-btns" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/play_icon.png" />';
  }
}

function vidMute(btn, vid) {
  var vid = document.getElementById(vid);

  if (vid.muted) {
    vid.muted = false;
    btn.innerHTML = '<img class="video-btns" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/sound_icon.png" /> ';
  } else {
    vid.muted = true;
    btn.innerHTML = '<img class="video-btns" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/sound_icon_muted.png" /> ';
  }
}

var numberOfGuests = document.getElementById("numberOfGuests");
var txtPrice = document.getElementById("txtPrice");
var txtToPrice = document.getElementById("txtToPrice");
var price = 7000;

numberOfGuests.oninput = function() {
  if (numberOfGuests.value > 0) {
    txtToPrice.innerHTML = (Number(numberOfGuests.value) + 1) * price;
  } else {
    txtToPrice.innerHTML = 7000;
  }
}
```

```css
.header {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(187, 243, 249, 1), rgba(70, 139, 186, 1));
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}

#logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2px;
  margin-left: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

#logo:hover {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 200px 5px #f5ff84;
}

.language {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -70px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 8px;
  border: none;
  width: 50px;
}

.language:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(187, 243, 249, 1), rgba(70, 139, 186, 1));
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 1px;
}


/* Dropdown Button */

.dropbtn {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 42px;
  height: 40px;
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Dropdown button on hover & focus */

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(187, 243, 249, 1), rgba(70, 139, 186, 1));
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
}


/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: right;
  padding-left: 75px;
  border: none;
}


/* search option */

#myInput {
  border-box: box-sizing;
  background-image: url('searchicon.png');
  background-position: 14px 12px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: verdana;
  padding: 16px 0px 15px 20px;
  border: none;
}


/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
}


/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #DBDBDB;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu (use JS to add this class to the .dropdown-content container when the user clicks on the dropdown button) */

.show {
  display: block;
}

#menu_icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 17px;
  padding-right: 7px;
}


/* reiser link */

#rl {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: default;
}

fieldset {
  border: none;
}

.form-booking {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(187, 243, 249, 1), rgba(70, 139, 186, 1));
  margin-top: 140px;
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 45%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 0px;
  margin-bottom: 82px;
}

.input-boxes {
  border: solid;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "ff-din-round-web", "ff-din-round-web-2", arial, helvetica, calibri, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #668c98;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-fill-color: #002f3d!important;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.box-wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120px;
}


/* Fornavn og Email */

.box-FEm {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 50%;
}

.box-FEm:hover {
  zoom: 1.2;
}


/* Etternavn og Mobilnummer */

.box-EtM {
  margin-left: 0.1%;
  width: 50%;
}

.box-EtM:hover {
  zoom: 1.2;
}

.label-text-FEm {
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 10%;
}

.label-text-EtM {
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
  margin-left: 1%;
}

p {
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
}


/*select-country-box*/

#scb {
  border: solid;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: "ff-din-round-web", "ff-din-round-web-2", arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid #668c98;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-fill-color: #002f3d!important;
  margin-left: 45%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5% 5% 5% 5%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}


/*label-text-choose-country*/

#ltcc {
  margin-left: 45%;
}

#tb {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border: none;
}

#bestill-btn {
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 40%;
}

#bestill-btn:hover {
  border-radius: 30px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 1px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #333;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
}


/*footer-text*/

.ftl {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 45%;
  width: 229px;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  border: none;
}

.ftr {
  position: relative;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 17px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  width: 130px;
  height: 20px;
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
  border: none;
}

.footer-100 {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}


/* footer-text-100 */

.f-txt-100 {
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 40%;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;
}


/* footer-media-icons*/

#fmi {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.footer-media {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 1%;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="header">
    <div>
      <!-- start div1 -->
      <a href="index.php"> <img id="logo" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/palm_logo_round.png"> </a>


      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/english/"><img class="language" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/english_icon.png"></a>
        <a href="bestill.php"><button class="dropbtn">BESTILL</button></a>

        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn"><img id="menu_icon" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/menu_icon.png">MENY</button>

        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
          <a id="rl" href="#">Reiser</a>
          <a href="brasil.php"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <img src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/Flag_of_Brazil.png"> &nbsp Brasil</a>
          <a href="kroatia.php"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <img src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/flag_of_croatia.png"> &nbsp Kroatia</a>
          <a href="thailand.php"> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <img src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/Flag_of_Thailand.png"> &nbsp Thailand</a>
          <a href="om_oss.php">Om oss</a>
        </div>
        <!--end myDropdown -->
      </div>
      <!-- end dropdown -->

    </div>
    <!-- end div1 -->

  </div>
  <!-- end header -->


  <div class="main">

    <form class="form-booking" action="registrert.php" method="GET">
      <!-- start form -->
      <fieldset>
        <p style="font-weight: ">Presonlig Informasjon</p>
        <br>


        <div class="box-wrapper">
          <!-- start box-wrapper for fornavn and etternavn -->
          <div class="box-FEm">
            <!-- start fornavn -->
            <label class="label-text-FEm" for="fornavn">Fornavn* </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input-boxes box-FEm" type="text" name="fornavn" id="fornavn" required autofocus placeholder="Fornavn" pattern="[a-åA-Å]{2,}" title="Fornavnet må inneholdet minst 2 bokstaver">
          </div>
          <!-- end fornavn -->

          <div class="box-EtM">
            <!-- start etternavn -->
            <label class="label-text-EtM" for="etternavn">Etternavn* </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input-boxes box-EtM" type="text" name="etternavn" id="etternavn" required placeholder="Etternavn" pattern="[a-åA-Å]{2,}" title="Etternavnet må minst ha 2 bokstaver">
          </div>
          <!-- end etternavn -->
        </div>
        <!-- end box-wrapper for fornavn and etternavn -->

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="box-wrapper">
          <!-- start box-wrapper for email and mobilnummer -->
          <div class="box-FEm">
            <!-- start email -->
            <label class="label-text-FEm" for="email">Email* </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input-boxes box-FEm" type="text" name="email" id="email" required placeholder="Email" pattern="[a-åA-Å]{3,}@[a-åA-Å]{3,}[.]{1}[a-åA-Å]{2,}" title="eksempel@hotmail.com">
          </div>
          <!-- end email -->

          <div class="box-EtM">
            <!-- start mobilnummer -->
            <label class="label-text-EtM" for="mobil">Mobilnummer* </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input-boxes box-EtM" type="tel" name="mobilnummer" id="mobilnummer" required placeholder="Mobilnummer" pattern="[0-9]{8}" title="Vennligst skriv inn minst 8 siffere">
          </div>
          <!-- end mobilnummer -->
        </div>
        <!-- end box-wrapper for email and mobilnummer -->

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="box-wrapper">
          <div class="box-FEm">
            <!-- start Postnr -->
            <label class="label-text-FEm" for="postnr">Postnr* </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input-boxes box-FEm" type="text" name="postnr" id="postnr" required placeholder="Postnr" pattern="[0-9]{4}" title="Vennligst skriv inn posadressen med minst 4 siffere">
          </div>
          <!-- end postnr -->

          <div class="box-EtM">
            <!-- start Poststed -->
            <label class="label-text-EtM" for="city, country">Poststed* </label>
            <br>
            <input class="input-boxes box-EtM" type="text" name="city, country" id="city, country" required placeholder="By, Land" pattern="[a-åA-Å]{2,}[,]{1} [a-åA-Å]{2,}" title="Poststedet må inneholde minst 2 bokstaver deretter komma (,) så mellomrom pluss minst 2 nye bokstaver">
          </div>
          <!-- end poststed -->
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>

        <div class="box-wrapper">
          <!-- start box-wrapper for land and date -->
          <div class="box-FEm">
            <!-- start land-div -->
            <label id="ltcc" for="land">Velg Land* </label>
            <br>
            <select id="scb" style="width:60%;" name="land" required title="Vennligst velg land ved å trykke på boksen">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="brazil">Brasil</option>
       <option value="croatoa">Croatia</option>
       <option value="thailand">Thailand</option>
      </select>
          </div>
          <!-- end land-div -->
        </div>
        <!-- end box-wrapper for land and date -->

        <br>
        <p>* Må utfylles </p>

      </fieldset>

      <br>

      <fieldset>
        <p style="font-weight: bold;">Bestillingsinformasjon</p>

        <p>For en person koster turen <span id="txtPrice">7000 </span>kroner</p>
        <br>

        <label style="font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;" for="numberOfGuests">Antall medreisende: </label>
        <input id="numberOfGuests" type="number" name="numberOfGuests" min="0" max="6" title="Vennligst sett inn antall medreisende ved bruk av knappene eller tastatur.">

        <br>
        <br>

        <label style="font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;" for="numberOfRooms">Antall rom: </label>
        <span style="padding-left: 65px;"> <input type="number" name="numberOfRooms" min="1" max="6"> </span>

        <p>Ønsker du middag på flyet?</p>
        <label for="jaMiddag">Ja: </label><input id="jaMiddag" type="radio" name="middag" value="jaMiddag">
        <label for="ingenMddag">Nei: </label><input id="ingenMddag" type="radio" name="middag" value="ingenMddag">

        <div id="tb">
          <p>Totalt <span id="txtToPrice">7000 </span>kroner</p>
        </div>
        <br>

        <input type="image" id="bestill-btn" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/bestill_button.png" alt="Bestill">
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    <!-- end form -->

  </div>
  <!-- end main -->


  <div class="footer">
    <div id="fmi">
      <!-- start footer-media -->
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"> <img class="footer-media" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons//facebook_icon.png"> </a>
      <a href="https://twitter.com/"> <img class="footer-media" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/twitter_icon.png"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/?hl=en"> <img class="footer-media" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/instagram_icon.png"> </a>
      <a href="https://www.youtube.com"> <img class="footer-media" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/youtube_icon.png"> </a>
      <a href="mailto:webmaster@example.com"> <img class="footer-media" src="http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/images/icons/email_icon.png"> </a>
    </div>
    <!-- end footer-media -->


    <div class="ftl">Copyright © 2017 LET's travel </div>

    <div class="ftr">Laget av LET AS</div>


  </div>
  <!-- end footer -->

</div>
<!-- end wrapper -->
```

Comment: You have a typo `txtToPrice`

Comment: What does it do, compared to what you expect?

Comment: Are you getting extra 7000? Is that the issue?

Comment: the issue is that i don't get anything at all, the numbers don't change

Comment: When I run the code in the above snippet the Totalt number changes when I edit in the Antall medreisende field.

Comment: There's a layout problem -- when the total has 5 digits it moves down a line, so it's partly covered by the numberOfRooms input.

Comment: the javascript works on this page, however not on mine for some reason :/

Comment: Also, you don't need to use `http://localhost/prosjekt_reiseklubb/...` for your links

Comment: it don't know why but  they won't show unless i do when i use browsersync

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your JavaScript code, you'll notice that there is a small spelling mistake. In the line:

`var txtToPrice     = document.getElementById("txtToprice");`

You have spelt `txtToprice` with a lowercase p instead of an uppercase P. If you change this your code should work.

Comment: I have changed it, but somehow it still doesn't work for me. It works on this site, but not on my webpage

Comment: Is the code definitely the same on this post and on your webpage? Also, could you edit your original question with a screenshot of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding 1 to the input value? If there's a value just multiple it by your cost, and default to 0..

```js
var numberOfGuests = document.getElementById("numberOfGuests");
    var txtPrice       = document.getElementById("txtPrice");
    var txtToPrice     = document.getElementById("txtToPrice");
    var price          = 7000;

    numberOfGuests.oninput = function() {
        if (numberOfGuests.value.length){
            txtToPrice.innerHTML = (Number(numberOfGuests.value)) * price;
        } else {
            txtToPrice.innerHTML = 0;
        }
    }
```

```css
#tb{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-top: -100px; 
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
<p style="font-weight: bold;">Paymentinformation</p>

<p>It costs <span id="txtPrice">7000 </span>for one person</p>
<br>

<label style="font-family: 'Embedded-DINWebPro', 'DIN Next W01 Regular', Arial, sans-serif;" for="numberOfGuests">Number of people: </label>
<input id="numberOfGuests" type="number" name="numberOfGuests" min="0" max="6">

<br>
<br>

<div id="tb">
   <p>Total <span id="txtToPrice">0</span></p>
</div>
<br>

</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

From how I read it, the question is "how to observe form changes with HTML and JavaScript and show a total." It would be best to simplify instead of trying to deal with all of the extra code provided. https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/6uv795gc/

```
<form id='myForm'>

  <div class='input-w'>
    <span class='label'>price</span>
    <input type='number' rel='price' value='75' />
  </div>

  <div class='input-w'>
    <span class='label'>number</span>
    <input type='number' rel='number' value='1' />
  </div>

  <p>
    <span rel='total'></span>
  </p>

</form>
```

...

```
// (jQuery included - to keep things readable)

var $myForm = $('#myForm');
var $price = $myForm.find('[rel="price"]');
var $number = $myForm.find('[rel="number"]');
var $total = $myForm.find('[rel="total"]');

var $inputs = $('#myForm').find('input');

$inputs.on('change', function() {
  var total = $price.val() * $number.val();
  $total.html(total);
}).trigger('change'); // once to start off
```

Comment: I am sorry i'm so horrible at this, but i do not know how to use jquery at all